# How to update Ubuntu from terminal using tor?

Tags: apt, tor

My college has a download limit, so I am not able to update my system. Can I use Tor to download updates?

Comment: Tor does not help reduce your usage. In fact, it might increase it

Comment: It greatly depends on how your college limit the bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `apt` with Tor, use the following commands:

```
sudo torify apt-get update
sudo -i
torify apt-get dist-upgrade
```

It will return lots of warnings, but it will work. Also, remember that the Tor network can sometimes be slow, so if it appears to freeze, just give it a couple minutes and it will go.